# COUNTIF function using a date range with ">"&TODAY()-N)

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to count all date instances for the past seven days *not* including today. The formula I am using is:

```
=COUNTIF($H$11:$H$501,">"&TODAY()-7)
```

In testing this formula, any dates equal to `TODAY()` are being selected.  I do not want to have any dates equal to today to be selected.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIFS` and add an additional criterion, that the dates are less than `TODAY`:

```
=COUNTIFS($H$11:$H$501,">"&TODAY()-7,$H$11:$H$501,"<"&TODAY())
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about a `SUMPRODUCT` approach first to create an array of legit dates to use withing an `OR` construct, but we can simply create that ourselves:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($H$11:$H$501,TODAY()-{1,2,3,4,5,6}))
```

If you want to be more flexible:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($H$11:$H$501,TODAY()-ROW(1:6)))
```

Do notice that @BigBen's answer will be the more common approach which you should adopt!

Comment: I like the first approach.